# All letters upright in math mode (equivalent to \rm)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, equations

I'm using the document class `scrartcl` and I'm looking for a way to write equations in which all letters are upright like it appears when using `\rm`.

```
\begin{equation}
    \rm A_{something} + B_{another} = C_{whatever}
\end{equation}
```

Because the use of `\rm` is deprecated my question is: is there way to achieve the same without enclosing every bit of text in `\text{}`?

```
\begin{equation}
    \text{A}_{\text{something}} + \text{B}_{\text{another}} = \text{C}_{\text{whatever}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Do you want this in *all* equations or just in selected ones? It's bad style anyway, however.

Comment: Do any of the ideas in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4155/15925 help?

Comment: I want it for some equations (not all of them). Preferably this would result in an extra environment and if I use renewcommand or newcommand doesn't matter then.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Well I don't want to "work around" this issue by selecting a whole new font I just want to be the current font upright in a certain scope. Is there a way to set this font-style explicitly?

Comment: @a_guest I think what you are after (at least what you said you are after) is wrong. `\text{A}_{\text{something}}` is *wrong*; the similar and correct thing would be `\mathrm{A}_{\text{something}}` (`A` is not text but a variable, if you want it to be upright then `\mathrm` is the way to go).

Comment: @Manuel: You are right, in fact I didn't want the effect of `\rm` in the first place, I just wanted the font of the scope to be upright and `\rm` was the only "easy" thing I could think of which did this (amongst other effects). Because `\mathrm{}` actually changes the font of the scope it does more than "required" (which is no problem for me, just as a general comment).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you like the effect of `\rm` but don't like that it is deprecated, then taking a look its implementation gives a good clue of what you can do.  In `source2e` you will find (see p.254 of [`source2e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en) 2017-04-15, where `\DeclareOldFontCommand` is defined)

```
 \DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
```

which means it is just `\mathrm` in math mode.  Thus you could write `\mathrm` around your equation contents instead.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{A_{something} + B_{another} = C_{whatever}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat solution for what I was asking! Just out of curiosity: I tried the same with `\text{}` instead of `\textrm{}` but this won't compile, I guess because of the underscores which can only be treated in math mode while `\text{}` "escapes" the math mode. Also using `\textrm{}` changes the whole font of the scope, doesn't it? And is there a way to make a new environment out of that?

Comment: `\text` is never going to work for this - it is switching you out of math mode, so underscores etc. are not allowed.  `\textrm` is essentially `\text` followed by a selection of the roman font, so has the same problem.

Answer (score 7):

If what you are after is an easy way of writing `\text` in subscripts, here's a way. You write `A_[something]` if you want `\text{..}` to be applied to the subscript.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\sbtext[#1]{\sb{\textnormal{#1}}}
\def\sptext[#1]{\sp{\textnormal{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~}{\@ifnextchar[\sbtext\sb}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\^\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def~}{\@ifnextchar[\sptext\sp}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_="8000 \catcode`\^=12 \mathcode`\^="8000 }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  A_[something] + B_[another] = C_[whatever]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also if one prefers `A_|something| + B^|something|` rather than `A_[something] + B^[something]` just change the definitions of `\sptext|#1|` and `\sbtext|#1|` and subsitute `\@ifnextchar|`.

Comment: It took me a while until I realized that ``\catcode`\_=12 `` was necessary. I couldn't understand why the code didn't work.

Comment: This works for the subscripts but I also want `A, B, C` to be upright. Something like `\mathrm{}` wrapped around the whole equation as in AndrewSwann's answer. I'm curious whether there is a way without changing the whole font but only its style.

Comment: I still don't understand why would you want `A` to be upright. This sentence *Because I think it looks clearer when dealing with long subscripts* is what I don't understand. If you actually are going to have `A_i` meaning something similar to `A_[something]` and one is going to be upright *just because it looks good when using long subscripts*, I think it's definitely wrong.

Comment: I think it's not about right or wrong it's just a matter of taste. `a+b=c` is something which can be true or false (or right or wrong, whatever) but if I deal with equations it doesn't really matter (to me) if letters are italic or not (when regarding their meaning). At least for me variables don't change their meaning only by the font they are written in. And my question is not about "is it good style to have all characters upright in an equation" it's about "how you can achieve this". If you're not comfortable with the style then why don't you regard it just as a challenge ;).

Comment: Your question *shouldn't be* (at least in this site) “is it good style..” but of course, answers can contain suggestions :) I would solve your problem with this solution, altough you don't like it. I leave it here, it might be of use for other people.

Comment: @Manuel, (+1) that is awesome, great answer! I'm always doing `_{\text{stuff}}`, it makes the code too polluted. Though sometimes upright superscripts come in handy, could you implement that to your answer? (I don't know how to fiddle with catcodes to do it myself `:/`)

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Done. May be you prefer `A_|text|`, I added an explanation below.

Comment: @Manuel, that is wonderful! I know it's very little code (thus easy to copy paste), but perhaps it could be made into a package `easyscripts` or something, with option to set the active character between `||`, `[]` and/or others. I know I'd be an active user... Unless it has compatibility issues I'm (we're?) unware of.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos If you mean that it could be broken with some rare code, almost definitely, but that depends on what weird things are you planning to write there. If it's just text then absolutely zero problems, for instance, if you write `A_[abc[def]ghi]` well, it doesn't work as you expect, but if you need that I can write a workaround. About the package, I see no need. You can write your own package if you prefer. If you need anything particular just ask.

Comment: @Manuel, I meant about conflict with other packages, if it was made into one... I'll put definetely only text there, maybe some `\theta` but nothing extraordinary. I think I'll write the package, to me this is very useful. Thank's for the update. `:)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Remember that if you want to write `\theta` you should use `A_\theta` or `A_{\theta}`, *not* `A_[\theta]` because that would be equivalent to `A_{\text{\theta}}` which gives an error. And it may conflict, but not very probable. If you have a particular problem, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear why you would do this; however, here it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{uprightmath}
 {\changecodes\ignorespaces}
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\changecodes}{%
  \count255=`A
  \loop
  \mathcode\count255=\numexpr\mathcode\count255-\string"100\relax
  \ifnum\count255<`Z
    \advance\count255 1
  \repeat
  \count255=`a
  \loop
  \mathcode\count255=\numexpr\mathcode\count255-\string"100\relax
  \ifnum\count255<`z
    \advance\count255 1
  \repeat
}

\begin{document}
Here the letters are normal
\begin{equation}
A_{x}+B_{y}=Z
\end{equation}
\begin{uprightmath}
But here they're upright $A_{something} + B_{another} = Z_{whatever}$
\begin{equation}
A_{something} + B_{another} = Z_{whateverz}
\end{equation}
and back to normal
\end{uprightmath}
\begin{equation}
A_{x}+B_{y}=C
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't we have something similar not so long ago? I remember some discussion about `\mathcode` _versus_ other approaches.

Comment: This is nice. Could you explain what you are doing? How to do the same with bold (like `\bf` in plain TeX).

Comment: @Manuel The mathcode of `a` is `"7161` so the letter is taken from math family 1. What I do is subtracting `"100` from the math code of all letters, so they're taken from family 0. Determine the number of the bold font family and you're done.

Comment: Quite a complex solution but seems to do the job and also to have pretty much flexibility regarding the font which you want to use! Why I want to have some equations in upright font? Because I think it looks clearer when dealing with long subscripts.

Comment: @a_guest semantically speaking, the right thing to do is to put only the subscripts in upright font, because the subscripts are text. But the main letters (A, B, C) are variables and would remain in math (italic) font.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't work with `unicode-math`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sure. Did I claim it does? I said, instead, it's a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks how to `write equations`, so this is not an answer in that sense. Here, I suggest a method on how to `draw` them.

Since `+` is an operation of coalescence, in general, and `=` indicates identity (such that `C` is `A` and `B` combined together), and since everything algebraic can be represented visually, the TikZ solution

[image: raindrops]

is presented by:

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=stealth,
    node distance=1.6cm,
    on grid,
    auto
  ]
    \node[state] (A)  [align=center,fill=blue!5]{{\large\textit{A}}};
    \node        (A1) [align=center,pos=0.25,left = of A,fill=green!15]{Raindrop\textit{\textsubscript{s\textsubscript{1}}}};
    \node        (S1) [below = of A]{};
    \node[state] (B)  [align=center,fill=blue!5,below=of S1]{{\large\textit{B}}};    
    \node        (B1) [align=center,left = of B,fill=green!15]{Raindrop\textit{\textsubscript{s\textsubscript{2}}}};
    \node[state,double] (C)  [align=center,fill=blue!5,right=of S1,minimum size=3.8em]{{\large\textit{AB}}};    
    \node        (C1) [align=center,right = of C,fill=green!15]{Raindrop\textit{\textsubscript{B\textsubscript{1}}}};
    \draw[->]   (A) edge (C);
    \draw[->]   (B) edge (C);    
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which may be easier for some to grasp, since mixing two styles (algebra and plain language) adds a cognitive load for the reader since they have to untangle the two and then compare how their meanings intertwine.

It becomes immediately apparent upon inspection that the AB combination, `C`, has properties different to its constituents (e.g., evenness), implying that the identity (`=`) is only a partial description. A transformation has also occurred, with the creation of a new entity.

The letters can be upright or italic, as one pleases.