# All letters upright in align mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I'm using the document class `article` and I would like to know if there is an easy way to write aligned equations with all letters automatically uprighted.

Since my equations contain lot of letters, I should use `\text` each time.

Looking for it I found [All letters upright in math mode (equivalent to \rm)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226518/all-letters-upright-in-math-mode-equivalent-to-rm) which suggests to use the `\mathrm` command. Unfortunately it does not seem to work when it contains the `&` symbol (which is needed in order to align the equations).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{TDD &= \frac{18}{9} = 2'}\\
    \mathrm{TF &= TI-TDD = 25-2 = 23'}\\
    \text{TR} &= \frac{18-5}{9} = 2'\\
    \text{TT} &= \text{TI}+\text{TRT}+\text{TD}+\text{TRS} = 25+2+5+1 = 33'
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the normal way would be to write `\mathrm{TDD}` although it is possible to change the default (probably an answer on site already I'll look...

Comment: I would use `\mathrm{TR}` and `\mathrm{TDD}` (not `\text`) but you could do this, replacing `\mathtt` by `\mathrm`  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63000/1090

Comment: Thank you! We are in the right direction, there is still a little problem in the visualization since two different fonts are used (one before the ``&`` sign, another one after it). Look here https://i.imgur.com/hqF3sLJ.png

Comment: No you forced a default of mathtt !! as I said you need that answer but using mathrm instead, also you need to remove all uses of \text and of course fix the brackets in any remaning `\mathrm` just to be around each identifier not spanning `&`) If you get an error such as `! Missing } inserted.` do not even look at the pdf output, it is just a possible debugging aid, tex makes no attempt at making sensible typeset output after an error.

Comment: Oh yes thanks, I replaced ``mathtt`` with ``mathrm``... it works! I just get this error:

Improper \halign inside ``$$``'s.

<recently read> \halign 

l.22 \end{align*}

Displays can use special alignments (like \eqalignno)
only if nothing but the alignment itself is between ``$$``'s.
So I've deleted the formulas that preceded this alignment.

Comment: that sounds like an unrelated error, hard to guess what you did wrong, but `align` should never be in math mode so I don't see how you could get that error or have formulas before the alignment? The code in my answer generates no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have `&` inside `{}` it is not really `\mathrm` that is causing the error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

Normal way
\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{TDD} &= \frac{18}{9} = 2'\\
    \mathrm{TF} &= \mathrm{TI}-\mathrm{TDD} = 25-2 = 23'\\
    \mathrm{TR} &= \frac{18-5}{9} = 2'\\
    \mathrm{TT} &= \mathrm{TI}+\mathrm{TRT}+\mathrm{TD}+\mathrm{TRS} = 25+2+5+1 = 33'
\end{align*}

I wouldn't do this
 \everymath{\mathrm{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
\begin{align*}
    TDD &= \frac{18}{9} = 2'\\
    TF &= TI-TDD = 25-2 = 23'\\
    TR &= \frac{18-5}{9} = 2'\\
    TT &= TI+TRT+TD+TRS = 25+2+5+1 = 33'
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solve all my problems! Why wouldn't you do that?

Comment: @soundwave because the fist form is much clearer especially if you alias \mathrm to something semantically relevant in your context such as `\newcommand\var{\mathrm}`  ... `\var{TR}` .....  and poking changes into the latex setup to change the defaults will work in your document  but mean you can not share those fragments in a mathjax website or some journal document class where changing the default styling would not be allowed or would break other code

Comment: You are right, but since this document I am working on it is only for personal use, it is good.

Comment: Anyway, the error I wrote before, is due to the command ``\everydisplay{\mathrm{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}`` which do the same work as the other one, but in the framework ``\[...\]``.

Comment: @soundwave ah,  yes, it would do that:-)

Answer (score 1):

A literal answer to your question is the `[math-style=upright]` package option of `unicode-math`, which you can switch on and off with the commands

```
\unimathsetup{math-style=upright}

\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO}
```

For example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=10cm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    TDD &= \frac{18}{9} = 2' \\
    TF &= TI-TDD = 25-2 = 23' \\
    TR &= \frac{18-5}{9} = 2' \\
    TT &= TI+TRT+TD+TRS = 25+2+5+1 = 33'
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Physics equation sample]

That said, I wouldn’t recommend you use this technique.  (Although I do recommend that you use `unicode-math` if you’re allowed to!)  The `\mathrm` solution is still supported and will work fine.

I personally find it handy to declare something like `\newcommand\TDD{\ensuremath{\mathop{\mathrm{TDD}}}}` and then write `\TDD` in the equations. If you might for some reason want to write `x \TDD` or `\TDD \TI` instead of `x \cdot \TDD` and `\TDD \cdot \TI`, the `\mathop` makes *x* TDD TI behave like log log *x* (that is, typeset like an operator name).

```
\documentclass[varwidth=10cm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{physics}

\newcommand\upvar[1]{\ensuremath{\mathop{\mathrm{#1}}}}
\newcommand\TD{\upvar{TD}}
\newcommand\TDD{\upvar{TDD}}
\newcommand\TF{\upvar{TF}}
\newcommand\TI{\upvar{TI}}
\newcommand\TR{\upvar{TR}}
\newcommand\TRS{\upvar{TRS}}
\newcommand\TRT{\upvar{TRT}}
\newcommand\TT{\upvar{TT}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \TDD &= \frac{18}{9} = 2' \\
    \TF &= \TI-\TDD = 25-2 = 23' \\
    \TR &= \frac{18-5}{9} = 2' \\
    \TT &= \TI+\TRT+\TD+\TRS = 25+2+5+1 = 33'
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This is just like typing `\log` or `\sin`.  An existing shorthand for this is `\operatorname{TDD}` from `amsmath`.