# Non italic text in equations

Tags: equations, amsmath, italic

Everytime I use an equation I want the normal letters to be non-italic in the equation.
I've tried `\usepackage{mathastext}` which makes the equations look funny, the parenthesis becomes small etc.
I've tried `\usepackage{eulervm}` Which rotates the `\leq`.

The greek letters can stay italic, I've got another trick to make them non-italic. Is there a way only to make the normal text in the equation non-italic?

Comment: @Denis I am thinking the OP wants the math symbols upright by default, not merely to add `\text` to a math environment...but I could be wrong.

Comment: Is there a way to do it globally in the preamble?
I've got a report her at approx 100 pages which is done.
Doing it manually would take too much time.

Comment: You can give a look to [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4155/82917).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if an approach like this would cover all bases?

I tell LaTeX to make math `letters` using the `{cmr}{m}{n}` font style.  However, this screws up Greek letters, so I have to define a special `greeksymbols` class that uses `{cmm}{m}{it}` and then, for each Greek symbol, point it to the `greeksymbols` font style.

EDITED to take campa's suggestion to add additional symbols to the mix, such as harpoons, `\imath` (upright style), `\wp`, and `\vec` (accent).

The key in adding such symbols is to look at the cm font tables in the TeXbook, (Appendix F), to determine the slot number and font family of the desired glyph.  You also need to know the functional category of glyph, such as `\mathrel`, `\mathbin`, `\mathchar`, `\mathord`, etc. and add all that information into the `\DeclareMathSymbol` declaration.

EDITED to make the greek letters `\mathord` category, per egreg's recommendation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}

%GREEKS
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"27}
%SYMBOLS
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftharpoonup}{\mathrel}{greeksymbols}{"28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftharpoondown}{\mathrel}{greeksymbols}{"29}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightharpoonup}{\mathrel}{greeksymbols}{"2A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightharpoondown}{\mathrel}{greeksymbols}{"2B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\wp}{\mathord}{greeksymbols}{"7D}
%OTHERS
\DeclareMathSymbol{\imath}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"10}
\DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathaccent}{greeksymbols}{"7E}
\begin{document}
\[
z = \alpha x + \beta y^2
\]
\[
x \leftharpoonup y \leftharpoondown z \rightharpoonup \imath \rightharpoondown i
\]
\[
A = \wp(\vec B)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx 
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OT1}{cmm}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
Was just what i was looking for.

Comment: BTW, i use this to greek letters: (Y) 
\usepackage{upgreek,xspace} % Non italic greek letters
\def\alpha{\ensuremath\upalpha\xspace}

Comment: I agree that this is the way to go, but it's still not perfect: some symbols will still be broken, not only the greek letters, e.g. some harpoons, `\imath`, `\wp`, and most importantly the arrow from `\vec` `:-)`. The list needs a couples of updates `:-)`

Comment: @campa Thank you for the valuable suggestions.  I have updated the answer to reflect it.

Comment: The Greek letters should be `\mathord`

Comment: @egreg Thanks.  I left `\imat` as `\mathalpha`, if that is right?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It depends on how you expect it to print in a `\mathit` context ( or similar).

Comment: Hello friend, my normal dots(punctum) became semicolon all over the report when i use this command: \DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n} . Do you know how i can fix this ?

Comment: \usepackage{sansmath} did the trick (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `unicode-math` with `math-style=upright` option. This works for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX though.

The following code built via `lualatex doc.tex` or `xelatex doc.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[
z = \alpha x + \beta y^2
\]
\[
x \leftharpoonup y \leftharpoondown z \rightharpoonup \imath \rightharpoondown i
\]
\[
A = \wp(\vec B)
\]
\end{document}
```

produces the following result

[image: upright fonts with unicode-math]

Note that Greek letters become upright as well.