# Math environment non-italic

Tags: math-mode

I write a textbook and I have completed 40 pages, but I don't like that the texts inside the $..$  are italic.
For example

*(x-3y)* not like

(x-3y) I want

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$(x-3y)$

\end{document}
```

What can I do to make the texts non-italic? Also, I don't want to change them all one by one.

Comment: It is the maths tradition to have italic letters for variables, at least for lowercase letters (in some countries, the tradition is to have non-italic letters for uppercase and the greek alphabet).

Comment: Sir you are absolutely right, but the book is for children 10-15 years old. When I browse such books, I can't see italic letters. So I wanted to do something like this.

Comment: The main problem is that those books are typeset with less powerful methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To globally change all math output to use upright lettering, for both latin and greek alphabet letters, I have the following suggestions:

- If you use pdfLaTeX to compile your document, load the `mathastext` package with the option `LGRgreek`.
- If you use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, load the `unicode-math` package and specify the option `math-style=upright` when you run the `\setmathfont` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\else
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[math-style=upright]
\fi

\begin{document}
$(x-3y)$ $\alpha\beta\gamma$ $ABC$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just this $\rm (x-3y)$, hope it will work

Comment: Thanks it worked, but What else can I do instead of changing all equations one by one?

Comment: Probably it takes more efforts. Read this, please https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/can-i-make-all-my-math-upright?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: `\mathrm{...}` it is the actual syntax instead of old notation `\rm`.